# Stack overflow in stored procedure (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo este procedimiento almacenado en PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ratpais_indcicloinmo() RETURNS trigger AS $ratpais_indcicloinmo$
    BEGIN
        UPDATE sde.ratpais SET indcicloinmo=(pond1cicloinmo)*(pond2cicloinmo)*(cicloinmo);
    END;

$ratpais_indcicloinmo$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER ratpais_indcicloinmo BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON sde.ratpais
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE ratpais_indcicloinmo();
```

El problema es que cuando lo ejecuto junto a su trigger, me da error de4 desbordamiento de pila porque no se puede usar UPDATE en la función y el trigger porque se genera una recursión que desborda la pila, pero no se como eliminar este problema...

Lo único que necesito con este código SQL es multiplicar 3 campos y guardar el resultado en otro campo ya creado, y esto debería ser automaticamente realizado (gracias al trigger) cada vez que se inserta un nuevo valor en la tabla.

¡Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo!

Comment: Buenas bienvenido a **StackOverflow** en español por favor antes de preguntar primero ve [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y revisa también [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) edita tu pregunta y mejorarla para tener una respuesta que realmente te ayude.

Comment: esto es un foro en espa;ol por favor edita

Answer (score 0):

En efecto, no debes usar una sentencia `UPDATE` para poner al día una columna en un trigger. Mas bien, en el trigger ya tienes acceso directo al registro que está siendo modificado y puedes acceder y modificar directamente las columnas de este registro usando la notación `NEW.columna`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ratpais_indcicloinmo() RETURNS trigger AS $ratpais_indcicloinmo$
    BEGIN
        NEW.indcicloinmo := NEW.pond1cicloinmo * NEW.pond2cicloinmo * NEW.cicloinmo;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$ratpais_indcicloinmo$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```